# NSPredicate and Core Data: retrieve objects among relationships

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data model structure like the following:

```
Product <-->> OrderProduct where the relationship (from Product to OrderProduct) is called productOrders while the inverse is called product

Order <-->> OrderProduct where the relationship is called orderProducts while the inverse is called order

Client <-->> Order where the relationship is called orders while the inverse is called client
```

Within an `UIViewController` I'm using a `NSFetchRequest` associated with the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY productOrders.order.client.code == %@)", clientCode];
```

The predicate works well. I'm able to retrieve products for one (or more) orders that are associated with a specific client.

Now I have to add another step. Find the last order (ordering by date) for a specific client. I've tried the following predicate but it doesn't work:

```
  NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY productOrders.order.client.code == %@ AND productOrders.order.@max.orderDate)", clientCode];
```

where `orderDate` is of type `NSDate`.

Do I have to use a SUBQUERY? How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue passing the date externally. In other words, I first calculated the last order date for a specific client and then I passed it to the interested element (the one that implement the request).

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY productOrders.order.client.code == %@ AND productOrders.order.orderDate == %@", clientCode, lastDate];
```

I don't know if could be correct but it works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When you need only one record you can indeed use a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sortDescriptor on your fetchrequest (fetchrequest takes an array of sortdescriptors).

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"productOrders.order.orderDate" ascending:NO];

[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

edit: see NeverBe comment

Comment: I'm not sure this could be a solution since the I created the request from Product entity.

Comment: When you use CoreData based on SQLite you can access the database directly. Sorting in code would be slow, since you'll need many CoreData calls.

Comment: This was a solution. You should set a correct key to sort descriptor (productOrders.order.orderDate) and set fetch limit to 1 for fetch request. also the sorting need to be desc

Comment: @ggfela Thank you for your edit. I'll try it as soon as possible. I'll let you know. Cheers.

Comment: @ggfela the descriptor doesn't work..do you have any other solution?

Comment: If you're not able to sort with a sortDescriptor you'll have to sort in code or when using SQLite directly accessing the database.